# Add Multiple Time Values to A UserForm

Tags: datetime, time, custom-controls

I need assistance with displaying multiple time values on a userform.  They will be listed in a list box and will need to remain static should a record require editing..  The user will not have access to the excel worksheet.  I need to didplay: time in: time seen; time out on the userform and on a hidden worksheet.  I can use the NOW function to record the current time when the customer fills out the form and submits their record(time in). How would I go about writing code that will record the time when the clerk retrieves the customer for service(time seen) and when the customer leaves the office(time out)?

Our clerks have to bring walkin customers in for service within 30 mins of arrival.  They also have to issue badges to customers with appointments within 30mins of arrival.  Hope that explanation helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about frontend technology then i will suggest Angular with Reactive forms where you can generate the form fields without writing multiple times by using form builder feature. follow below link to know more.

[Angular Reactive form guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Thank you for responding. This looks to be the solution to my issue.  I am very new to VBA and self taught.  I've built what i have currently using YouTube....lol.  I will check our the guide and let you know how it turns out.  Thanks again!